# SDL_Event->key.keysym.sym symbol keys (colon, double quote, question mark...)

Tags: c++, user-interface, keyboard, sdl

https://web.archive.org/web/20130728100527/http://www.libsdl.org:80/docs/html/sdlkey.html

Here are the key enums listed in the SDL documentation.
Specifically for this question we only need a subset.

```
SDLK_COLON      //value is 58 (ascii)
SDLK_SEMICOLON  //value is 59 (ascii)

//Code Example illustrating question
void KText::OnKeyDown(SDLKey key, SDLMod mod, Uint16 unicode) {
    if(key == SDLK_COLON) exit(1);
}
```

When I hit semicolon, clearly it won't exit.  When I hold shift and hit semicolon (keying a colon) it still doesn't exit.  I've tested, no matter if I'm holding shift or not it throws the default key.  This could be by design or it could be a bug.  I could simply say well, if I'm holding shift and key semicolon then I should use colon instead.  However that seems rather a pain to remap all the keys while holding shift.

Has anyone else found a work around for this?

Edit:

Looking at values inside the function for key indicate the key is the same regardless of holding shift or not and it's not specific to semicolon/colon.  It's the same for all keys (makes sense for letter keys sense there is no SLDK_A only SDLK_a, but for brackets, quotes, greater than/less than, dollar sign, etc they do not show up only the base key)

Comment: Have you tried debugging it, e.g. printing what "key" value you have?

Comment: Indeed.  Exit(key) is 59 regardless if I'm holding shift or not

Comment: or stopping and looking at values.

Comment: So, perhaps you can just check for "SDLK_SEMICOLON && mod & (KMOD_LSHIFT|KMOD_RSHIFT)"? Of course, that won't work on, say, a Swedish keyboard, as ":" is on the same key as ".", not the same key as semicolon.

Comment: Alternatively, you could look at the `unicode` value, I suppose... ;)#

Comment: I was afraid of that.  
For some reason the unicode is always 0.  I'll have to do some more looking into the key documentation on SDL.

Comment: Try calling `SDL_EnableUNICODE(1);`

Comment: It even had it listed in the link I posted about Unicode.  I just didn't pay attention because I thought key would do it :)  Well, when holding shift and hitting semicolon, unicode is 58 but hitting semicolon it is 59.  Works correctly with unicode :)

Comment: Ok, so I've written an answer to that effect... ;)

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: @JesperJuhl not helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after much commenting back and forth: To correctly read the keyvalue, the `unicode` value should be used, which means `SDL_EnableUNICODE(1);` somewhere in initialization of the program (so that `unicode` gets filled in - it does add a tiny bit [in most cases, it's function call to a function that performs a lookup in a table of some sort, but it may be a little more than that] of extra processing, so if it's not needed, it's wasted to try to translate every keypress to their respective actual unicode value).